# PHP Cli -Helpful Information when developing backend processes

Tags: php, performance

I really just wanted to know a bit more about the PHP Cli with a few more specific questions that I had.. I know that it is much better to use the CLI for more intense background processes than using php on apache, as it helps (save memory?).. however I'm wondering can you run multiple instances of the cli concurrently? IE: having multiple crons run different commands via the CLI? or how exactly does that work?

I have numerous background processes that I need to run, which are pretty intensive and I wanted to write them all via the CLI so they would not disturbe apache, and just wanted a little more information on how exactly it functioned, if it allowed multiple instances of it to run at a time with different items.

Thank you in advance for your kindness and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple cronjobs running simultaneously - they run as different processes, do not interfere with eachother.
I have a datamining site with 7 different cronjobs, at least one of them is almost always running, but usually 2+ do at the same time.